# Session to store temporary data in MVC

Tags: session, model-view-controller

I am pretty new to development and MVC. I want to use session to store my data in a multi page survey, (using next and back buttons to save in the last page). Most of the topics for sessions are about login infos. Can any one help me please.

Comment: `Session["yourKey"]="SomeValueYouWantToStore";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use $_SESSION['YOUR KEY'] = "ANY VALUE";
try this above code it might be help you have to use $_SESSION instead of SESSION.

```
<input type="radio" value="1" <?php if($_SESSION['YOUR_KEY'] == 1) { echo "selected";} ?>   >
 <input type="radio" value="2" <?php if($_SESSION['YOUR_KEY'] == 2) { echo "selected";} ?>   >
```

Add the if condition in input radio

Comment: Thanks Kunal, it works fine now, But I was not able to use that with my back button too. Atually I dont know how to select a radiobutton from what I have in my session.

Comment: i edit my answer see it