# Session values not passed to another php page on an online hosted website

Tags: php

I have created a session in my index.php but when I tried to pass it to another page it shows that the value of the session is null, this only happens when I'm using a hosted site (Online server). It does not give me any problem when I'm using local machine (local server  == wampserver).

This is the code of index.php:

```
<?php session_start(); 
if(!isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
    $_SESSION['userID'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['avatar'] ="";
} else { 
    $_SESSION['userID'] = "001";
    $_SESSION['fName'] = "john";
    header('Location:dashboard/parent.php');
}
```

This is the code of the second (receiving) page where I'm trying to access `$_SESSION['fName']`.

```
<?php session_start(); echo" '.$_SESSION['fName'].' ";?>
```

`$_SESSION['fName']` is null here.

Comment: Go through this Link. I already answer this quetion
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392306/session-to-store-temporary-data-in-mvc/39395958#39395958

Comment: @kunal If you feel that this question already has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392306/session-to-store-temporary-data-in-mvc/39395958#39395958) then flag this question as a **duplicate** of the other one.

Comment: I've included your code to your question so other people can understand your question better. Please see [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Comment: This echo looks so wrong.

Comment: Try to use `<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['fName']; ?>` No need the quotes, double quotes, since you not concatenating anything, you just want to `echo` it.